# How can I see what is triggering a "transaction check vs depsolve" error?

Tags: rhel, yum, packaging

I have inherited a software project which builds a set of RPMs to be installed on a RHEL server. When I attempt to install the packages on a server, I get a "transaction check vs depsolve"  error saying the package requires libc.so.6. I have found that the error will go away if I install glibc.i686.

The problem here is that this package is supposed to be for the x86_64 architecture and shouldn't depend on 32-bit libraries. Is there a way I can find what is triggering the error? All of the binaries in the package I have checked so far are built for x86_64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up extracting the RPM and using a one-liner to find the offending binaries:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 file | grep 'ELF 32'
```

This listed all of the 32-bit binaries in the directory.